# Tokenize String in Python with Optional components

Tags: python, string, parsing, nlp

I'm building a simple webapp in Flask and wanted to be able to tokenize strings which fit a certain format and get the variables. An example would probably help understand this

```
if input_string = 'play me a song by eminem'
  artist = eminem
  action = play

if input_string = 'play me a sad song by eminem'
  artist = eminem
  action = play
  emotion = sad

if input_string = 'play me a sad song'
  emotion = sad
  action = play
```

I'm not looking at Natural Language processing, but rather just picking up tokens if they exist. I'm looking at the format string [play/show/do] a {[emotion]} [song/image/video] { by [artist]} about {[topic]}

where everything in {} is optional, and should be None/null if not present in the string

I'm unsure how to proceed though. Would Regex be the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

This is just one (straight forward) possibility of 1000s, however it may give you a direction to dig. Notice that there is almost no error check:

```
class Command(object):
    def __init__(self, input_string):
        words = input_string.split()
        self.artist = self.get_artist(words)
        self.action = self.get_action(words)
        self.emotion = self.get_emotion(words)

    def get_artist(self, words):
        try:
            index = words.index('by') + 1
        except ValueError:
            return 
        else:
            return words[index]

    def get_action(self, words):
        return words[0]

    def get_emotion(self, words):
        index = words.index('song') - 1
        emotion = words[index]
        return emotion if emotion is not 'a' else None

>>> from tokenise import Command
>>> command = Command('play me a song by eminem')
>>> command.artist
'eminem'
>>> command.action
'play'
>>> command.emotion
>>> command = Command('play me a sad song by eminem')
>>> command.artist
'eminem'
>>> command.action
'play'
>>> command.emotion
'sad'
>>> command = Command('play me a sad song')
>>> command.artist
>>> command.action
'play'
>>> command.emotion
'sad'
```